# visual studio 2012 c++ error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I just started to learn c++ and I wanted to show an arry in promt but i get this weird error

this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void _show(char a[10][10])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
            cout<<a[i][j];
}
void _main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char a[10][10];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
            a[i][j]=0;
    _show(a);
}
```

and this is the error:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: You want `_tmain`, not `_main`. And unless you're creating some project type that requires VisualC++ extensions, I'd lose the `#include <stdafx.h>` (and turn off pre-compiled headers); and replace `void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` with `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: You should find another source for your learning. You are using plenty of non-c++ constructs here.

Comment: More on the [main function here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function). Note that the `_TCHAR` thing is not standard C++, but is standard for a certain C++ implementation. Also, see [this list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: can you give me a good menual to learn from?

Comment: You are also accessing out of bounds. Needs to to <10 rather than <11

Comment: @user2302416 As first, I would start learning classic C over C++.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is missing "main" function (which is used as entry point from OS). This function MUST have name: `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` (for classic console based application)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use underscores  [here is an explanation why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1345339) as they are reserved

main function should be declared as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```